# Why does current() not work with foreach() in PHP 7?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to understand this code :

```
$array = [0, 1, 2];
foreach ($array as &$val) {
    var_dump(current($array));
}
```

In PHP 5.6 the result would be `int(1) int(2) bool(false)`, in PHP 7 the result would be `int(0) int(0) int(0)`. The question is why?

Why isn't the result in both cases the values of the array `0, 1, 2`? I understand that `current()` in PHP returns the current value, so each time the foreach goes over each one, isn't the current value that should be printed out?

Comment: @PaulCrovella you just linked what I don't understand ;-) Care to explain please? I don't understand what's in the doc.

Comment: From the docs: _The end of an array and the result of calling current() on an empty array are indistinguishable from a boolean FALSE element. To properly traverse an array which may contain FALSE elements, see the foreach() function. To still use current() and properly check if the value is really an element of the array, the key() of the current() element should be checked to be strictly different from NULL. _

Comment: @gumakettell The answer is in the link, "_Prior to PHP 7, the internal array pointer was modified while an array was being iterated over with foreach. This is no longer the case ..._"

Comment: + http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php (first "Note" section)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton as I said, I don't understand what's in the link x) The English it's written in is too much for me to understand. I'm not dumb, I can read what's written. When I asked the question it was to get a better explanation than the 2 lines written in the mentioned doc.

Comment: Just use $val and keep your code simple.

Comment: @gumakettell Okay well, prior to PHP 7, foreach modified the internal array pointer to match which iteration it was on, it no longer does that. `current()` returns "_the current element in an array_", which is specified by the internal array pointer, so prior to PHP 7, this pointer would change, but it no longer does, so `current()` always returns the same thing (inside a foreach, given you haven't changed the pointer yourself). There isn't really much more you can add to the description, maybe you should research what an internal array pointer is?

Comment: like @user1597430 says : _In PHP 7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer_ so in your  var_dump(current($array)); always return the first element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The implementation of `foreach` was changed in PHP 7.0 as [described in this migration note](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.foreach):

> Prior to PHP 7, the internal array pointer was modified while an array was being iterated over with foreach. This is no longer the case.

The `current()` function returns the element pointed at by the "internal array pointer", a concept from older versions of PHP which is rarely used in modern code. This can be used as an alternative looping mechanism with [the `each()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.each.php) which is deprecated in PHP 7.2.

In older versions of PHP, `each()` and `foreach` both changed this "internal array pointer", so you could mix `foreach` and `current` as shown in the example. However, this meant the internal code was unnecessarily complicated and slow for some cases, so it was changed in PHP 7.0. Now, `foreach` tracks its position in the array in a different way, which `current()` does not read.

Comment: That's a simpler explanation than the migration note, thank you!